# How to use Bazel to build project uses OpenCV

Tags: opencv, bazel

What is the best way to build C++ code that uses the OpenCV library using Bazel? I.e., what would the BUILD rules look like?

How should be the `WORKSPACE` and `BUILD` files look like in order to compile the following code using bazel:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "iostream"

int main(int, char**) {
  using namespace cv;
  VideoCapture cap(0);
  Mat save_img; cap >> save_img;
  if(save_img.empty())
  {
    std::cerr << "ERROR >> Something is wrong with camera..." << std::endl;
  }
  imwrite("test.jpg", save_img);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this was closed for looking for offsite resources... it isn't.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  The easiest way is probably to install locally in the way the OpenCV site recommends:

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv/
mkdir build install
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/opencv/install ..
make install
```

Then add the following to your WORKSPACE file:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "opencv",
    path = "/path/to/opencv/install",
    build_file = "opencv.BUILD",
)
```

Create `opencv.BUILD` in the same directory as WORKSPACE with the following:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp"]),
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
    linkstatic = 1,
)
```

Then your code can depend on `@opencv//:opencv` to link in the .so's under lib/ and reference the headers under include/.

However, this isn't very portable. If you want a portable solution (and you're feeling ambitious), you could add the OpenCV git repo to your workspace and download & build it.  Something like:

```
# WORKSPACE
new_git_repository(
    name = "opencv",
    remote = "https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git",
    build_file = "opencv.BUILD",
    tag = "3.1.0",
)
```

And make opencv.BUILD something like:

```
cc_library(
    name = "core",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = glob(["modules/core/src/**/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "modules/core/src/**/*.hpp", 
        "modules/core/include/**/*.hpp"]
    ) + [":module-includes"],
)

genrule(
    name = "module-includes",
    cmd = "echo '#define HAVE_OPENCV_CORE' > $@",
    outs = ["opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"],
)

...
```

Then your code could depend on more specific targets, e.g., `@opencv//:core`.

As a third option, you declare both cmake and OpenCV in your WORKSPACE file and use a genrule to run cmake on OpenCV from within Bazel.

Comment: Thanks so much! I went with the easiest option (the first one). Some minor corrections if anyone is using OpenCV 3.1.0: cc_library(
  name = "opencv",
  srcs = glob([ "lib/*.so*" ]),
  hdrs = glob([ "include/**/*.hpp" ]),
  includes = [ "include" ],
  visibility = [ "//visibility:public" ],
  linkstatic = 1,
)

Comment: @kristina the second solution is not portable neither. there is a lot of missing files that are generated when running cmake, not only `opencv_modules.hpp`

Comment: @Ghilas I think you are missing what I meant by "portable:" if your build works for you, you can hand it to your coworker and it'll work on their machine, too.  If the build doesn't expose the artifacts you need, it's not a portability problem.

Comment: @kristina The code in `opencv.BUILD` don't work as is, even if my code only needs `@opencv/:core`, that's what I meant. I've found a more complete code [here](https://github.com/hatstand/symmetrical-octo-fiesta/blob/28714db06cfbb4574efa00d395facbb3e53024b6/BUILD.opencv) that works. Now the only thing that I'm looking for is how to expose the JNI functions of OpenCV as I use the library from Java too. Any Idea ?

Comment: @kristina on mac I'm getting a linker error like this. Any idea? ```Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from ...```

Comment: @kristina. I follow your advice and build a project. But got a very wired error: The building process finish normally. but when I try to run the program. I have this error:  bazel-bin/main/hello-world: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  I don't even use opencv in my code, just add opencv add deps. here is my code, just a very simple helloworld program. can you take a look? https://github.com/scotthuang1989/tools_study/tree/master/bazel/opencv_app_bazel

Comment: This cmake command works: `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

Comment: I had some of the errors above and it seems that's its related to probably: opencv versions or different machine OSs. Given that, it is important that we check the contents and routes we are defining in the `WORKSPACE` and `opencv.BUILD` files. For example, as I'm writing this comment in 2020 in a machine running macOS, opencv's srcs are `.dylib`, different from `.so`, and some of the headers have `.h` extension not only `.hpp`, and so on. So one recommendation would be to check every route in the `install` folder and see if everything is matching our definitions.

Comment: the second solution is not explained well, and it doesn't work.

Comment: "Prefer `http_archive` to `git_repository` and `new_git_repository`. The reasons are:

Git repository rules depend on system `git(1)` whereas the HTTP downloader is built into Bazel and has no system dependencies,
`http_archive` supports a list of `urls` as mirrors, and `git_repository` supports only a single `remote`.
`http_archive` works with the repository cache, but not `git_repository` " [Best Practices](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an up2date solution that works with the current set of `bazel`(v3.1.0). In this little project i wanted to build a C++ program that depends on the newest `openCV` release (4.3.0), but only on a selected set of modules (core,highgui,imgcodecs,imgproc).

No local installed `openCV` required, `bazel` loads the needed files from github (although it works even when there is an old version of `openCV` installed):

Content of `/WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

all_content = """filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])"""

http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "opencv-4.3.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.3.0.zip"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-master",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/master.zip",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//:workspace_definitions.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()
```

Content of `/BUILD` file:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:cmake.bzl", "cmake_external")

cmake_external(
    name = "opencv",
    cmake_options = [
        "-GNinja",
        "-DBUILD_LIST=core,highgui,imgcodecs,imgproc",
    ],
    lib_source = "@opencv//:all",
    make_commands = [
        "ninja",
        "ninja install",
    ],
    out_include_dir = "include/opencv4",
    shared_libraries = [
        "libopencv_core.so",
        "libopencv_highgui.so",
        "libopencv_imgcodecs.so",
        "libopencv_imgproc.so",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And finally, your target that depends on `opencv`, in my case a file `/opencv/BUILD`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = ["opencv.cpp"],
    data = [
      "LinuxLogo.jpg",
      "WindowsLogo.jpg",
    ],
    deps = ["//:opencv"],
)
```

If you want to try it out, here is the rest: [blackliner/automata](https://github.com/blackliner/automata/tree/master/opencv)

```
git clone https://github.com/blackliner/automata.git
cd automata
bazel build ...
```

Comment: Tried to use it under Windows 10 with CMake 3.17.2 building for Visual Studio 2019 Win64 (i.e. `cmake_options=[-G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A"Win64"`], make_commands = ["MSBuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj"]). Does not work with PowerShell. Switched to MSys2 shell - does also not work - I guess this was tested using Linux?

Comment: Ok, wait, CMake? This is about using Bazel instead of CMake. What exactly did you try to do? And yes, i used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: `cmake_external` calls CMake. I used Bazel 3.1.0 to test it under Windows 10. But cmake_external works currently not for Powershell since it uses bash scripts. Even on msys2 shell I run into problems...

Answer (score 3):

I succeed with  @kristina's first option.

1. Install opencv:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

   cd opencv/

   mkdir build install

   cd build

   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

   make install
   ```
2. Change WORKSPACE file (at tensorflow/WORKSPACE cloned from github)

   ```
   new_local_repository(

   name = "opencv",

   path = "/usr/local",

   build_file = "opencv.BUILD",

   )
   ```
3. Make opencv.BUILD file at the same place as WORKSPACE file:

   ```
   cc_library(

   name = "opencv",

   srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),

   hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp"]),

   includes = ["include"],

   visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 

   linkstatic = 1,

   )
   ```
4. You may have to config the opencv libs path:

a. Make sure you have /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf file with content:

```
    /usr/local/lib
```

b. Run the command:

```
    sudo ldconfig -v
```

Comment: How do I include int my BUILD file?

Comment: Make sure to get the .h files too. Not sure how this worked for others.  This is what my build looked like:

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/opencv2/**/*.h",
        "include/opencv2/**/*.hpp",
        ]),
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    linkstatic = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

Comment: Humm, when I do this i'm still getting tons on undefined reference/ 
In my deps, I added @opencv. if I do @opencv//:core bazel cries with not defined

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for OpenCV 2.4.13.2, `core/` only. This approach goes from the opencv source, which is adapted from the accepted answer above by @kristina.

The first thing is to add the http_archive for the opencv 2.4 release:

```
# OpenCV 2.4.13.2
new_http_archive(
    name = "opencv2",
    url = "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/2.4.13.2.zip",
    build_file = "third_party/opencv2.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "opencv-2.4.13.2",
)
```

And then, add the file `third_party/opencv2.BUILD` as:

```
cc_library(
    name = "dynamicuda",
    hdrs = glob([
        "modules/dynamicuda/include/**/*.hpp",
    ]),
    includes = [
        "modules/dynamicuda/include"
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "core",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = glob(["modules/core/src/**/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "modules/core/src/**/*.hpp",
        "modules/core/include/**/*.hpp",
     ]) + [
        ":module_includes",
        ":cvconfig",
        ":version_string",
    ],
    copts = [
        "-Imodules/dynamicuda/include",
    ],
    # Note that opencv core requires zlib and pthread to build.
    linkopts = ["-pthread", "-lz"],
    includes = [
        "modules/core/include",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":dynamicuda",
    ],
)

genrule(
    name = "module_includes",
    cmd = "echo '#define HAVE_OPENCV_CORE' > $@",
    outs = ["opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"],
)

genrule(
    name = "cvconfig",
    outs = ["cvconfig.h"],
    cmd = """
cat > $@ <<"EOF"
// JPEG-2000
#define HAVE_JASPER

// IJG JPEG
#define HAVE_JPEG

// PNG
#define HAVE_PNG

// TIFF
#define HAVE_TIFF

// Compile for 'real' NVIDIA GPU architectures
#define CUDA_ARCH_BIN ""

// NVIDIA GPU features are used
#define CUDA_ARCH_FEATURES ""

// Compile for 'virtual' NVIDIA PTX architectures
#define CUDA_ARCH_PTX ""
EOF"""
)

genrule(
    name = "version_string",
    outs = ["version_string.inc"],
    cmd = """
cat > $@ <<"EOF"
"\\n"
)
```

Note that I did not put anything in the `version_string.inc`. It is just a C++ string literal which does not affect the functionality of OpenCV. If you are really interested in this file see this [example](https://github.com/matoilic/thesis/blob/master/Libraries/opencv/modules/core/version_string.inc).

After this you should be able to add target with dependencies on `@opencv2//:core`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo of OpenCV & C++ built with Bazel: https://github.com/jcju/opencv_bazel_win

You may set up the OpenCV path in WORKSPACE and run:

```
bazel run //src:main
```

Comment: I tested it on Window 10 x64+ Powershell + Bazel 3.1.0 - `linkstatic = 1` has no effect. I can compile my OpenCV code, but when running it complains about mission OpenCV DLLs.

Comment: If it shows missing of DLLs, the most convenient way is to add opencv into Windows Environment Variables. For example: open Environment Variables list -> Edit "PATH"-> add [C:\opencv]/install/[x64]/[vc14]/bin; replace the opencv path and VS version with your settings.