# Building dlib C++ code using Bazel

Tags: dlib, bazel

What is the best way to build C++ code that uses the dlib library using Bazel? I.e., what would the BUILD rules look like?

I tried following the [answer for OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984290/building-opencv-code-using-bazel) as follows, but had no luck:

```
cc_library(
  name = "dlib",
  srcs = glob(["build/dlib/*.so*"]),
  hdrs = glob(["dlib/*.h"]),
  includes = ["include"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
  linkstatic = 1,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Assuming dlib was unzipped to /opt/dlib-19.2 and built in /opt/dlib-19.2/build.

In your WORKSPACE file:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "dlib",
  path = "/opt/dlib-19.2",
  build_file = "dlib.BUILD",
)
```

In dlib.BUILD:

```
cc_library(
  name = "dlib",
  srcs = glob(["build/dlib/*.so*"]),
  hdrs = glob(["dlib/**/*.h"]),
  includes = ["."],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
  linkstatic = 1,
)
```