# OSX Tensorflow + Opencv: Symbol Not Found, expected in Flat Namespace

Tags: opencv, bazel

I use OSX10.12, I try to use OpenCV in tensorflow, I use the first method which is mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984290/building-opencv-code-using-bazel).

I build my code successfully but there are some questions as following when I execute it:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv6String8allocateEm
Referenced from: /Users/philokey/Practice/github/tensorflow/./bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/test_cv/test_cv
Expected in: flat namespace
```

The build file is as following:

```
cc_binary(
name = "test_cv",
srcs = [
    "test_cv.cc",
],
deps = [
    "@opencv//:opencv",
],
)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you updated following files under tensorflow directory, correctly:

in WORKSPACE - (./tensorflow/tensorflow/WORKSPACE) add following:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "opencv",
  path = "/usr/local/",
  build_file = "opencv.BUILD",
)
```

opencv.BUILD - (./tensorflow/tensorflow/opencv.BUILD) add following:

```
cc_library(
  name = "opencv",
  srcs = glob(["lib/*.dylib*"]),         <<<<<<<
  hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp"]),
  includes = ["include"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  linkstatic = 1,
)
```

[NOTE] for different operating systems, different dynamic libraries are created, example:

1. linux -> *.so,
2. windows -> *.dll, and
3. on OSx -> *.dylib

Even then if you face any problems please set `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARY` environment variable to check if the correct libraries are linked, at times different versions of libraries may keep you busy.