# Building a CMake library within a Bazel project

Tags: tensorflow, build, cmake, bazel, nanomsg

I've written a module on top of a private fork off of TensorFlow that uses [nanomsg](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg).

For my local development server, I used `cmake install` to install nanomsg (to `/usr/local`) and accessed the header files from their installed location. The project runs fine locally.

However, I now need to package nanomsg within my TensorFlow workspace. I've tried the following two approaches, and find neither satisfactory:

1. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024014) for OpenCV, I precompiled nanomsg into a private repository, loaded it within my workspace (within `tensorflow/workspace.bzl`) using an [http_archive directive](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#http_archive) then included the headers and libraries in the relevant build script. This runs fine, but is not a portable solution.
2. A more portable solution, I created a `genrule` to run a specific sequence of `cmake` commands that can be used to build nanomsg. This approach is neater, but the `genrule` cannot be reused to `cmake` other projects. (I referred to [this discussion](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2532)).

Clearly `cmake` is not supported as a first-class citizen in Bazel builds. Is there anyone who has faced this problem in your own projects created a generic, portable way to include libraries within Bazel projects that are built using `cmake`? If so, how did you approach it?

Comment: How portable do you want it to be? Linux, MacOS, Windows? For 2, why is it a problem that you can't use the same genrule for other projects? I work on Bazel, and so far I haven't heard of anyone who's come up with a generic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ulf wrote, I think your suggested option 2 should work fine.

Regarding "can I identify if the cmake fails", yes: cmake should return with an error exit code (!= 0) when it fails. This in turn will cause Bazel to automatically recognize the genrule action as failed and thus fail the build. Because Bazel sets "set -e -o pipefail" before running your command (cf. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule-environment), it should also work if you chain multiple cmake commands in your genrule "cmd".

If you call out to a shell script in your "cmd" attribute that then actually runs the cmake commands, make sure to put "set -e -o pipefail" in the first line of your script yourself. Otherwise the script will not fail when cmake fails.

If I misunderstood your question "Can I identify if the cmake fails", please let me know. :)

Answer (score 6):

This new project: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc seems like a solution(it build rules for cmake to build your project inside bazel).