# import CMake project to Bazel project

Tags: c++, cmake, bazel, dbus

I have project in Bazel wchich required
https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp/tree/master   (dbus,CMake,Bazel,linux)

to work, but this library is written using CMake, how can I attach it to my project?
I try to rewrite CMakeLists to BUILD file but but it does not make sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hope this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146441/building-a-cmake-library-within-a-bazel-project)

Comment: Definitely give [rules_foreign_cc](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/main/index.html) a go (also mentioned in the link in the other comment). It served me well.