# How to import OpenCV android-sdk to my project which is using Bazel?

Tags: bazel, android, opencv

I have been trying to import [opencv-android-sdk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) to my Bazel project but I am not able to do it.

I tried the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024014/9889901) on SO but while building my project I get errors that

`error: package org.opencv.android does not exist`

Comment: Can you please share what your BUILD and WORKSPACE files look like?

Comment: This is what my [WORKSPACE](https://pastebin.com/VwjBgEQk), [opencv.BUILD](https://pastebin.com/Gbay5YST) and [app/BUILD](https://pastebin.com/25TpxJi7). But what I think is that the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984290/building-opencv-code-using-bazel/35024014#35024014) I referred to was for C++ project not for android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there's an `opencv-android` [artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opencv/opencv-android/1.0.1) on Maven.

You can depend on this using [`rules_jvm_external`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opencv/opencv-android/1.0.1).

In your `WORKSPACE` file, specify the dependency along with the other external dependencies:

```py
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "org.opencv:opencv-android:1.0.1",
        # ...
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],
)
```

Then, in your `BUILD` file containing your Android targets, depend on the OpenCV target:

```
android_library(
     name = "my_lib",
     custom_package = "com.example.bazel",
     srcs = glob(["java/com/example/bazel/*.java"]),
     manifest = "java/AndroidManifest.xml",
     resource_files = glob(["res/**"]),
     deps = [
         "@maven//:org_opencv_opencv_android",
     ],
     visibility = ["//src/test:__subpackages__"]
)
```

Finally, you should be able to reference classes like `org.opencv.core.Core` in your Android Java code.

P.S. consider switching all your `maven_jar` and `gmaven_rules`/`gmaven_artifact` to use `rules_jvm_external`. The former Maven rules have been deprecated in favor of `rules_jvm_external`.

Comment: Thanks Jin, I updated Bazel from 0.15 to 0.24.1 and it works perfectly.