# using bazel to build opencv

Tags: opencv, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I tried to follow the following instruction. I attempted two methods one with new_local_repository the other with http_archive.

[How to use Bazel to build project uses OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984290/how-to-use-bazel-to-build-project-uses-opencv)

In both situations, including @opencv in main BUILD file actually worked. But I got stuck on once I start to include "#include". The vscode editor seems to understand where the header files are but bazelisk build will generate error related to can't find header.

main/hello-world.cc:7:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: Error means there is no visibility for that directory. Can you share the code?